# Creating an ungreedy regex in Sublime Text 3

Tags: regex, sublimetext3

How do I create an ungreedy regex in Sublime Text 3? Neither the `\U` nor the `?` syntax seem to work.

This is my line of code:

```
if (isset($data) === false && is_null($data) === false && is_array($data) === false) {
```

And this is my regex:

```
(is(.+)\(\$(.+)\) === false)?
```

I should get nine separate matches (tested in [Regexr](https://regexr.com/4i9pr)):

```
isset($data) === false
set
data
is_null($data) === false
_null
data
is_array($data) === false
_array
data
```

Ready to replace with `!is\2($\3)`, but it's capturing the entire statement, not three individuals.

Comment: Maybe something like `\bis(\w*)\(\$([^()]*)\)\s*===\s*false\b` will do? See [the demo](https://regex101.com/r/Ne3kWt/1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this: `is([^(]+)\(\$([^)]+)\) === false`

replaced with `!is\1($\2)`

see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/dL6zG1/8)